# I'm trying to make a Python trading bot using the Coinspot API

Tags: python, authentication

I want to create my own python trading bot using the [Coinspot API](https://www.coinspot.com.au/v2/api), but I'm having trouble authenticating my secret.

(I'm fairly new to the whole programming scene)

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import json

api_key= b"AAA-BBB-CCC"
secret= b"AAA-BBB-CCC"
url="https://www.coinspot.com.au/api/v2/ro/status"

payload = {
    'nonce': int(time.time() * 1000)
}

payload_json = json.dumps(payload)


sign = hmac.new(secret, payload_json.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'key': api_key,
    'sign': sign,
}


response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, params=payload)

print(response.text)
```

It keeps returning:

> <Response [401]>
> or

> {"status":"error","message":"invalid/missing nonce"}

(Depending on if I print `response.text` or just `response`).

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution with some minor changes.

The 'nonce' integer in the Payload JSON had to be enclosed in quotes, which is done by enclosing in the `str()` function.

Extra space after the colon in the Payload JSON would cause the request to fail, this is fixed by adding the `separators=(',', ':')` arg to remove it.

Lastly, the `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` JSON within the header would also cause a bad request, so I removed it.

Final code:

```
import requests
import hmac
import hashlib
import time
import json

api_key = b"AAA-BBB-CCC"
secret = b"AAA-BBB-CCC"
url = "https://www.coinspot.com.au/api/v2/ro/status"

payload = {
    'nonce': str(int(time.time() * 1000))
}

payload_json = json.dumps(payload, separators=(',', ':'))


sign = hmac.new(secret, payload_json.encode(), digestmod=hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()

headers = {
    'key': api_key,
    'sign': sign,
}

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```